# Spring Data - Query By Example result different from JPQL result

Tags: java, spring, spring-data-jpa

During a Unit test i found a small "odd behavior" on query example.

I have the following entity definition (Keycloak entity model).

the second result list is inversed, usually i don't use examples on nested attributes but since it worked it is just odd. that the list of example is not the same as the query. also i mention that is not an issue for me... i just tried to simplify the talk with the DB with an Example.of...

```
public class RoleEntity {
    @Id
    @Column(name="ID", length = 36)
    @Access(AccessType.PROPERTY) // we do this because relationships often fetch id, but not entity.  This avoids an extra SQL
    private String id;

    @Nationalized
    @Column(name = "NAME")
    private String name;
    @Nationalized
    @Column(name = "DESCRIPTION")
    private String description;

    // hax! couldn't get constraint to work properly
    @Column(name = "REALM_ID")
    private String realmId;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "REALM")
    private RealmEntity realm;

    @Column(name="CLIENT_ROLE")
    private boolean clientRole;

    @Column(name="CLIENT")
    private String clientId;

    // Hack to ensure that either name+client or name+realm are unique. Needed due to MS-SQL as it don't allow multiple NULL values in the column, which is part of constraint
    @Column(name="CLIENT_REALM_CONSTRAINT", length = 36)
    private String clientRealmConstraint;

    @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = {})
    @JoinTable(name = "COMPOSITE_ROLE", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "COMPOSITE"), inverseJoinColumns =   @JoinColumn(name = "CHILD_ROLE"))
    private Set<RoleEntity> compositeRoles;

    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.REMOVE, orphanRemoval = true, mappedBy="role")
    @Fetch(FetchMode.SELECT)
    @BatchSize(size = 20)
    protected Collection<RoleAttributeEntity> attributes;
}

 @Table(name = "ROLE_ATTRIBUTE")
@Entity
public class RoleAttributeEntity {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "ID", length = 36)
    @Access(AccessType.PROPERTY)
    protected String id;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "ROLE_ID")
    protected RoleEntity role;

    @Column(name = "NAME")
    protected String name;

    @Nationalized
    @Column(name = "VALUE")
    protected String value;
}

@Repository
public interface RoleEntityRepository extends JpaRepository<RoleEntity, String> {
    
    @Query(value = "select r from RoleEntity r inner join r.attributes ra where ra.name = 'action'")
    List<RoleEntity> getSysmatActionRoles();
    
}


I executed this unit test as bellow. 

@Test
    void assertQueryResultRoleAttributeEntity() {
        RoleEntity roleEntitySample = new RoleEntity();
        RoleAttributeEntity rae = new RoleAttributeEntity();
        rae.setName("action");
        roleEntitySample.getAttributes().add(rae);
        Example<RoleEntity> exampleRole = Example.of(roleEntitySample);
        List<RoleEntity> lr1 = roleEntityRepository.findAll(exampleRole);
        List<RoleEntity> lr = roleEntityRepository.getSysmatActionRoles();
        assertNotNull(lr);
        assertTrue(lr.size() > 0);
        lr
        .stream()
        .forEach(r -> {
            System.err.println(r.getName());
        });
        //utializando example resultado incorreto.
        assertNotNull(lr1);
        assertTrue(lr1.size() > 0);
        lr1
        .stream()
        .forEach(r -> {
            System.err.println(r.getName());
        });
        
    }
```

Just Extented the Unit Test to determine the problem.
Spring Data Example does not verify the Lazy Collections (attribute in question).
Second unit test is bellow.
Problem solved using the RoleAttributeEntity on example

```
@Test 
void assertQueryResultRoleAttributeEntity() {
    RoleAttributeEntity rae = new RoleAttributeEntity(); 
    rae.setName(SYSMAT_ACTION_NAME);
    Example<RoleAttributeEntity> ex = Example.of(rae);
    List<RoleAttributeEntity> list = roleAttributeEntityRepository.findAll(ex);
    list
    .stream()
    .forEach(r -> {
        System.err.println(r.getRole());
        //assertTrue(list1.size() == 1);
    });
}


Regards.
```

Comment: Sorry, what is different to what? What SQL statements get actually executed?

Comment: You mean, the log of the query findAll?  i will perform on monday(25) the test again. and put the of the execution of the findAll(example)..

Comment: I understood what is happening. the attribute ClientRole is a "boolean native" and the findAll(example) is not checking the collections (ont to many attributes), this is ok for me (i understant the complexity). the odd behavior on result if the "native boolean"..

Comment: Rendered criteria query -> select generatedAlias0 from RoleEntity as generatedAlias0 where generatedAlias0.clientRole=:param0
 select roleentity0_.ID as id1_28_, roleentity0_.CLIENT as client2_28_, roleentity0_.CLIENT_REALM_CONSTRAINT as client_r3_28_, roleentity0_.CLIENT_ROLE as client_r4_28_, roleentity0_.DESCRIPTION as descript5_28_, roleentity0_.NAME as name6_28_, roleentity0_.REALM as realm8_28_, roleentity0_.REALM_ID as realm_id7_28_ from KEYCLOAK_ROLE roleentity0_ where roleentity0_.CLIENT_ROLE=?

Comment: just to mention 
`@Column(name="CLIENT_ROLE")
    private boolean clientRole;` since is native is "false"

and `Example.of (roleEntity)` does not verify the lazyCollection (attributes) of the Entity `RoleEntity`

Comment: Concluding and "thiking a little bit more"... this is the expected behavior, since the relationship is LAZY.. is will check changing the boolean to Boolean and puting EAGER (just in case).

Comment: using an Example<RoleAttributeEntity>  the unit test worked. by the OneToMany does not passed. thanks.

Comment: Could you make this a proper answer, so others have a chance of finding it and also the question can get marked as answered?